# limit email domain - vaidation yii

Tags: yii

I have `email` field in `signup` form ,

I want to validate email domain with database e.g

```
Email adress is : example@work.com  or etc@etc.com
```

Now I want validate that `work.com` or `etc.com` is listed in db or not , if not then it should not be vaidate.!

Can Anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
public function validate($attributes = null, $clearErrors = true) {
    parent::validate($attributes, $clearErrors);
    if (!$this->hasErrors('email')) {
        $a = explode('@', $this->email);
        if (isset($a[1])) {
            $record = AllowedDomains::model()->findByAttributes(array('domain'=>$a[1]));
            if ($record === null) {
                $this->addError('email', "This domain isn't allowed");
            }
        }
    }
    return !$this->hasErrors();
}
```

Notes:

- put this code in the model
- email - the field holding the email address
- AllowedDomains - the CActiveRecord of the table that holds the allowed domains
- domain - replace with the correct database field
- don't forget to add the e-mail validator in the rules() function. This will filter out invalid email addresses and the above code will not run if something's wrong

Comment: Could be done like this, but if you have hundreds of attributes that need to be validated the validate function will become one big giant mess :-)

Comment: Thanks... Good example with the hundreds of attributes... :D The main idea is to avoid running the validator if the email address already has errors

Comment: @icefront , It showed me this error 

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php on line 219

Comment: I removed recursive function call and it worked !
parent::validate($attributes, $clearErrors);

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by adding a custom yii validator in the rules section of your Model. Here is some example code:

```
public $email; // This is the field where the email is stored

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       array('email', 'checkDomain'),
    );
}
```

Afterwards, you can add the custom validation function

```
public function checkDomain($attribute,$params)
{
    $sEmailDomain = substr(strrchr($this->email, "@"), 1);

    // Check if the domain exists
    ...
    // If the domain exists, add the error
    $this->addError('email', 'Domain already exists in the database');
}
```

More information can be found here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/